# Nested Stack Implementation

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, stack

I am trying to implement a nested stack structure, basically a standard stack encapsulated inside a custom stack. I am uploading the code.

```
struct Advstack
{
    stack* mainStack=NULL;
};

void pushNew(struct Advstack* new_stack, int val)
{
    new_stack->mainStack->push(val);
}

int main()
{
    struct Advstack* new_stack;
    pushNew(new_stack, 2);
}
```

This code is giving me `segmentation fault` which I am not able to make out why is it giving so.
**PS:** I have included the necessary header files required namely *bits/stdc++* and *stack*.

Comment: C++ will not even compile your code at line `stack<int>* mainStack=NULL;`  in particular.

Comment: Why use pointers?  Just declare a non-pointer member `stack<int> minStack` and your problems are solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_stack` is uninitialized.  You need to create an instance of `Advstack` before using it.  You also never assign its member `mainStack` to an actual stack.  This should fix your segfault:

```
    struct Advstack* new_stack = new Advstack;
    new_stack->mainStack = new stack<int>();
    pushNew(new_stack, 2);
    delete new_stack->mainStack;
    delete new_stack;
```

Comment: Why using a pointer `struct Advstack*`,  and applying `new()`/`delete` at all?